# Changing Margins

Tags: margins

How do you change margins? I looked up a solution, but it said something like "one inch + \hoffset". Are there any other ways to change the margin?

Comment: the easiest way to specify margins is to use the geometry package

Answer (score 1):

If you are using OpTeX (or OPmac macros) then there is the `\margins` macro:

```
\margins/1 a4 (2,2,2,2)cm  % 2 cm margins in A4 paper
or
\margins/2 a5 (15,22,14,20)mm % 2-pages layout, outer margins 22, inner 15mm
                              % top margins 14mm bottom 20mm
```

You can specify arbitrary paper dimensions, you can omit some values for margins (then `\hsize` or `\vsize` are kept unchanged). See more information in the OpTeX documentation.

Note: OpTeX sets the page origin to left top paper corner, no to 1in 1in coordinate. The old position at 1in 1in (decision by D. Knuth) is leaved in OpTeX because this bring only wasteful complications when margins are calculated.

Answer (score 0):

Some classes, like `memoir` (`texdoc memoir`), provide simple ways to set margins and other aspects of the page layout. For general use there is the `geometry` package (`texdoc geometry`) for specifying the page layout.